# How do i make the moving and disappearing hearts in the background

Tags: animation, video

I just started out, asked around every blender discord group i could to get some help, no answers hopefully ill get them here.

[here's the link](https://youtu.be/K93iyIHdQp4?si=7J0SP5gLLpMNP3Qp)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: He uses a particle system, check some tutorials about particle system/Emitter

Comment: Noted and thanks <3 ur the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to comment the same as @moonboots - if you are unfamiliar with particle systems, I would highly recommend to do some tutorials to learn how they work. But I thought, I'll give a quick overview how this can be done. But that's just the tip of the iceberg and you should really learn more about it to know what these settings are all about. First of all I assume you have modeled a heart object, this is just for the particle system:

1. Add a plane to the scene and give it a *Particle System*.
2. Set the *Emission* settings to your liking.
3. Set a *Velocity* to your liking, to make the particles move upwards this could be the *Normal* velocity for example. Maybe set *Randomize* to a small amount as well.
4. Enable *Rotation*, set the *Orientation Axis* to *Global Z*, and set some value between 0 and 1 for *Randomize Phase* depending on how much variation you want in the Z rotation.
5. Go to the *Render* section, set *Render As* to *Object* and choose the heart as *Instance Object*. Set the *Scale* to your liking and also the *Scale Randomness*.
6. Now finally to make sure the hearts do not fall down, go to *Field Weights* and set *Gravity* to 0.

Result:

[image: hearts floating upwards]

Settings I mention above:

[image: particle settings]

Comment: <3 AYOOO thanks for taking the time to show me, honestly much appreciated.